# I don't know why I'm getting an error simply by creating a new Clock object

Tags: java, time, clock

I am getting an error that says "Cannot instantiate the type Clock" and I do not know why.

```
import java.time.Clock;
public class TS1 {

    public long getTime(){
        Clock c = new **Clock**(); //Error occurs here for bold Clock
        return c.millis();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the javadoc for Clock? The constructor is protected: only available to child classes.

Comment: So how do I fix it? Also just extending the clock class forces me to add a bunch of fluff that I don't want.

Comment: Again, read the javadoc. Clock has several static methods allowing to create several kinds of Clocks.

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.time/Clock/Clock.millis_.htm) example for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [javadoc of class Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) (added in java 8):

> The primary purpose of this abstraction is to allow alternate clocks to be plugged in as and when required. Applications use an object to obtain the current time rather than a static method. This can simplify testing.

To use the `millis()` method of the abstract `Clock` class , you don't have to extend it, you can use given implementations in java.time package. For example, you can declare the following method:

```
import java.time.Clock;
public class App {
    public static long getMillis(Clock clock){
       return clock.millis();        
    }
}
```

In your you app you can get a system clock implementation, rather using a direct and static calling to `System.currentTimeInMillis()`:

```
Clock systemClock = Clock.systemUTC();
System.out.println(getMillis(systemClock));
```

This app code depends on the operating system clock and it result varies between each running time.

In your test code, you can use a fixed clock instance, so the results are deterministic and predictable, regardless of the testing time (Certainly, for many testing scenarios you would use a mock object):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

@Test public void checkSampleUTCTime(){
    Clock fixedClock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2016-04-21T11:54:20.00Z"), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    assertEquals(1461239660000L,App.getMillis(fixedClock));
}
```

Also, some would say that joda time `DateTimeUtils` class ([see javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html)) is nicer option - since you can use `setCurrentMillisFixed()` and `setCurrentMillisSystem()` to alternate the system clock behavior, instead of `java.time.Clock` dependency injection.